# Scrape website using agilitypack

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

Im using this code:

```
  HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
        doc = hw.Load("http://stats.nba.com/scores.html?gameDate=04/11/2014");
        HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='scoreboards']/div");
```

And the html looks like this:

[image: HTML]

I want to get all the childnodes to the div with the class "items clearfix"

When i scrape with this

```
("//div[@id='scoreboards']/div");
```

i get the two divs [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBnjs.png) and [2] so my guess would be to do like this:

```
   ("//div[@id='scoreboards']/div[2]/div");
```

So that i get the divs underneith div[2] but that gives me "Null".

All i want is the gameid of each of the divs.

Comment: why not `//div[@id='items clearfix']/div`?

Comment: @har07 because it might not be unique. But it doensn't realy work. @class="items clearfix" gives me null aswell

Comment: @har07 if i use this "//div[@class='items clearfix']/div" it returns null and if i use this "//div[@class='items clearfix']" it finds the div but it does'nt have any childnodes

Comment: I see, so it's not unique. How about this way : `//div[@id='scoreboards']/div[@class='items clearfix']/div` ?

Comment: @har07  its the same there. ("//div[@id='scoreboards']/div[@class='items clearfix']") gives me that div but without childnodes and this: //div[@id='scoreboards']/div[@class='items clearfix']/div gives me null

Comment: @har07 could the problem be that the divs is generated from javascript? http://stats.nba.com/scores.html?gameDate=04/11/2014
and that is why it can't find the divs?

Comment: It seems so. To make sure, you can save html page received by HAP : `doc.Save("stats_nba.html")`